# System.IO.out of memory exception was unhandled for defining List

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory

Directory is quite big around 2 GB. I have defined a new List named results in which it will fetch all the values.

My code is here :

```
IEnumerable<string> textLines =  
              Directory.GetFiles(@C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\watson_query\, "*.*")
                        .Select(filePath => File.ReadLines(filePath))
                        .SelectMany(line => line)
                        .Where(line => !line.Contains("appGUID: wx"))
                        .ToList();

string searchKeyword = "WX Edit Bug";
List<string> results = new List<string>();

textLines.ToList().ForEach(textLine =>
{
   if (textLine.Contains(searchKeyword))
   {
      results.Add(textLine);
   }
});

int WX_Edit = results.Count;
Console.WriteLine("WX_Edit_Api=" + WX_Edit);
```

Comment: what is your question? in which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: in File.ReadLines(filePath), exception is thrown.

Comment: `OutOfMemoryException` isn't it obvious what it means? You're loading too much data in memory at once. You need to optimize your code

Comment: Haven't you asked the exact same question yesterday?

Comment: Try without the ToList().  And why not just do both Contains in the first?

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing `textLines = [...].ToList()` and then later you're calling `textLines.ToList()`. If you had to remove elements from `textLines`, it would make sense to create a copy of it to iterate through, but in this context it not only makes no sense, it also (almost) doubles your memory consumption (though the exception happens sooner already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `SelectMany`/`ToList` with `ReadLines` as it'll enumerate all lines of file and store the huge result in memory. You could enumerate `ReadLines` using a `foreach`, or manually use a `StreamReader` to only read line by line. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx for example.

Also, if only the count is relevant, use an `int` value you increment, and avoid storing result in `List<string>`.

Have a try with:

```
string searchKeyword = "WX Edit Bug";
int WX_Edit = Directory.GetFiles(@C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\watson_query\, "*.*")
                        .Select(filePath => File.ReadLines(filePath))
                        .SelectMany(line => line)
                        .Count(line => !line.Contains("appGUID: wx") && line.Contains(searchKeyword));
```

Comment: What's wrong with `File.ReadLines`? It does *not* read the entire file at once.

Comment: @DominicKexel My bad, I read the question too fast. The LINQ stuff after File.ReadLines is the issue.

Comment: It's just the call to `ToList()`. `SelectMany` is implemented by using deferred execution, so that's not a problem.

Comment: What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Accepted answer with a down vote.  Interesting.   +1